# Moving back and forth between dierctorys in AWK

Tags: awk

In AWK, how can I move back and forth between directories using “cd” command?

To illustarte what I am looking for, here is a small senario:

If a root directory includes subdirectory called subD. Now, assume that I have the awk srcipt code '*.awk' in the root directory, and I would the awk program to move to the subdirectory "subD", run a program, and return back to root directory.

Comment: gawk has a [`chdir` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Internal-File-Description)

Answer (score 2):

Use the absolute path to the files that you're reading so you don't need to change the current working directory inside your code.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is better to put only text processing logic to awk code, and things like directory traversal in shell script calling that awk code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `system(cmd)` to run the external command `cmd`.